# How can I add a toolbar to the top of my iPhone app's screen without it looking like it's upside-down?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

when i add a toolbar in IB to the top of the screen, the toolbar style is upside down (border at the top of toolbar and no border at the bottom).

is there any way of changing the toolbar so it looks normal and the border is at the bottom? I cant seem to find a way of doing it in IB, am i going to have to code it?

Comment: How about a navigation bar? Provided you don't cram it with non-navigational elements that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're breaking the [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1) if you try and put it at the top.

> On iPhone, a toolbar always appears at the bottom edge of a screen or view, but on iPad it can instead appear at the top edge.

So the toolbar always looks like that on iPhone. Breaking the HIG in this way is likely to get your app rejected from the app store.

Comment: ah right i see. i was using the toolbar with a segmented control to filter between annotations on a map view. to add this segment control to the root view controller nav bar would i have to code it? becuase i cant drag and drop using interface builder, unless i drag a new navigation bar onto the view and hide the root view controller. but i guess this is bad practice right?

Comment: If you are trying to change the appearance of standard controls, you're better off doing it in code. It's easier in the long run that hacking around hiding and showing standard toolbars just so that you can use IB. IMO, of course.